# stack a 2d array into an existing 3d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I start by initializing:

```
3dArray = np.zeros(shape=(0,250,2))
```

Within a loop, I go through a file and pick out sections of data, resulting in multiple 2D arrays of size (250,2).

For each of these sections, I'm trying to stack these 2d arrays into the 3d array, so that the 0th dimension increases by 1 every time, i.e., 3dArray is of shape (1,250,2), then (2,250,2) etc.

I tried using:

```
3dArray = np.dstack((3dArray, new2DArray))
```

Comment: It's better to collect all 2d arrays in a list, and then do just **one** `stack` or `dstack`.  All those `concatenate/stack` functions takes a list - use that feature!

Comment: Never mind, figured it out, thanks again!

Comment: list append is efficient

Answer (score 1):

```py
3DArray = np.vstack((3DArray,new2Darray.reshape(1,250,2)))
```

Side Note: Python doesn't allow variable names to start with numbers.